# Using blender as a video converter for multiple files?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Can you use Blender to convert a bunch of, say, AVI files into .MP4 files? I need to convert about 17 .AVI video files into SEPARATE .MP4 files, but I cannot find any free video converters.

Comment: You can,, but consider looking into  ffmpeg via command line or shell script, VLC media player or handbrake as 3 readily available cross platform video converters. With handbrake for example can simply open a folder with the avi files, set the output format and let it crunch away.

Comment: **(readily available.... and free)

Comment: You can use blender, but why bother. There are better tools to do this, and free of charge.

Use ffmpeg directly.

It will be faster and you have a lot more options to encode. If you don't want to use a terminal (or console) there are a lot of Frontends like [**WinFF**](https://github.com/WinFF/winff) or [**ffmpegyag**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpegyag/). For easy conversion into mp4 use [**handbrake**](https://handbrake.fr/)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20video%20converters&oq=free%20video%20converters&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.8187j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: after 5 hours of googling and struggling with codec settings in VLC to maintain the same perceptual color space during conversion, when most of codecs seem to remove grey/black details on .MOV videos shoot with DSLR camera, and Blender somehow automagically maintain gamma i want... i believe this question becomesan absolute gem for people tired of learning inner workings of each thing just to use it once/twice

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct conversion for this in Blender, but you can do this kind of thing using the *Video sequencer/editor* in the video editing tab of blender. First you open the video editing tab:[image]
And then press SHFT+A to open a dropdown menu that will give you the option to add a *movie*. Press this, and Blender will take you to a browser. Select the movie (.avi) you want, and press 'select'. Now you have added a .avi (if you selected that) in your sequencer:[image]
Now you can have the *output* of the video type set, and then sequence the video to a location of your choice:[image]
Now you can *render animation* like you would any normal animation, and it will automatically sequence through the video editor, and output your video.

Comment: but if I have multiple files can I export them as mp4s in multiple files instead of just one long one?

Comment: There may be a solution with headless/command line blender or python scripting i will try to give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but only using python automation.

TLDR:
I know this is not python related, thats why i can spare you the details
i wrote a script that does that
https://gist.github.com/Osmiogrzesznik/7752fb7d934721462a64b6592f2ee7ef
just paste it into text editor on scripting tab in empty blender file, set up your render settings regarding colors etc. and browse to the folder you want to convert. script will get those files one by one , putting them as a Movie Strip and rendering them out to folder specified in your render output, additionally this script can render to the same folder and the same extension if you will name your output file based on "prefix___postfix" pattern where three underscores will be replaced by source file name. I am currently happily typing this answer while its churning through 148 files on my sd card :)

Since Blender allows users to write python scripts and create plugins it exposes an API (Application Programming Interface). Thankfully it uses one of the easiest to read (not sure whether easiest to code in ) programming languages - Python.

This is why by reading the documentation, forums etc. we can choose interesting us classes from those exposed for users machinations by blender system `ImportHelper` etc., it is possible to turn Blender into anything including countless prior attempts such as CAD software, CNC, or Vector Graphics editor, possibly even Word processing software.

Your question is definitely a valid option, since most of softwares mentioned in comments do not make the process of conversion intuitive if it comes to color settings and adding content to rendered output. In my case i needed a conversion process for multiple movie files recorded with a flat color profile in a .MOV format(google searches confirmed quicktime format being notoriously problematic in other softwares regarding gamma correction and color profile). Since i dont know about these things, and blender conversion seems to know what i mean by "maintain the perceptual color space", and i know a bit of python...

by using Scripting Tab in your blender you can write and run scripts.
you can open provided templates in the menu. Python shell/console in this tab allows you to run live commands to test thing by casual poking stuff around.

By using ImportHelper class, and creating modal operator that registers itself as handler for some events you can execute code in the moments of something occuring:

```python
bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(self.onRenderComplete)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_init.append(self.onRenderInit)

        bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.append(self.onRenderCancelled)
```

You can create a class that registers those handlers, and on each render_complete takes out next item from list of files, then appriopriately sets up the videosequencer and scene to render the strip to a new file.

I will edit this answer later to provide some actually useful details on the process, but it may be blender-python related. I am currently exploring running this in headless blender (command-line blender) and making this a free plug-in.